# If $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = 1/2$, then why is it impossible that $\mathbb{P}(B | A) = 1 /3$?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I work with statistics and encountered this question. Have read about conditional probability and the formula under says that $\mathbb{P}(B|A)$ is the proportion of $A$ that is also $B$.

$$P(B|A) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$$

done a little research but can not find anything about this formula that gives an impossible answer.

Someone that has a clue?

Comment: $P(A)$ would have to be greater than $1$.

Comment: Why do you expect an impossible answer?

Comment: From $\Pr(B\mid A) = \dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A)}$, rearranging gives you $\dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B\mid A)}=\Pr(A)$ and so plugging in the stated values, $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{1/2}{1/3}=1.5$

Answer (score 0):

We have that $P(B|A) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$. We are given that $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = 1/2$. We must prove that it is impossible to have $\mathbb{P}(B | A) = 1 /3$. Substitute the value we have into the expression to get $P(B|A) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)} =\frac{1/2}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$. We also have $\mathbb{P}(B | A) = 1 /3$, so our expression becomes  $ 1 /3=\frac{1/2}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$. Solving for $\mathbb{P}(A)$, we get $\mathbb{P}(A)=3/2$. However, we know that is impossible, because probabilities must be between $0$ and $1$. Thus, it is impossible to have $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}(B | A) = 1 /3$ be true at the same time.

Comment: As @ElliotG explained in a one-line comment...

Comment: Yes, I saw that, I was just posting a thorough answer @TonyK

Comment: I understand, thank you! @SomeGuy